# Ignore catch block if try throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typeorm

I have a try catch block where I try to find the user and if user is found I throw error inside try block.
I am trying to catch only the database error inside the catch block. Now I know when I throw an error from try block it will be caught by catch block and ultimately whatever inside the catch block only will be thrown.

```
try {
  const exists = await User.findOne({ username });
  
  // if user exists throw this and not go inside catch block
  if (exists) throw new Error('username');
} catch (e) {
  // if database error only throw this
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
}
```

I tried this approach and it works fine for my use case

```
try {
  const exists = await User.findOne({ username });

  if (exists) throw new Error('username');
} catch (e) {
  if (e.message === 'username') throw new Error('username exists');
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
}
```

but I think this is pretty repetitive here and also inside my controller I have to check the message and based on the message I have to send different errors like this

```
try {
  const user = await userService.createUser(username, password);
  return res.status(201).json(user);

} catch (e) {

  if (e.message === 'username exists') return res.status(409).json(e.message);
  return res.status(500).json(e.message);
}
```

Is there a way I can get around this and ultimately remove `if (e.message === 'username') throw new Error('username exists');` line inside the catch block

PS: Answers that doesn't require me to initiate 'exists' inside global scope first and based on that use multiple try catch blocks are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about defining a new method which will throw error when there's a db error or return the user if found.

And we can make use of this in another method for eg., consider `createUser` and based on the return value we can return the error without handling the error in catch.

```js
const isUserExists = async username => {
  try {
    return await User.findOne({
      username
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong');
  }
}

const createUser = async username => {
  const isExists = await isUserExists(username)
  if (isExists) {
    throw new Error('username');
  }
  // ...rest of the code 
}
```

For simplicity, below I have simulated all 3 scenarios

- DB Error

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
async function isUserExists(username) {
  try {
    return await User.findOne({
      username
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong');
  }
}

async function createUser(username) {
  const isExists = await isUserExists(username)
  if (isExists) {
    throw new Error('username');
  }
}

createUser("test")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
</script>
```

- User found

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
async function isUserExists(username) {
  try {
    return await {};
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong');
  }
}

async function createUser(username) {
  const isExists = await isUserExists(username)
  if (isExists) {
    throw new Error('username');
  }
}

createUser("test")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
</script>
```

- User not found

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
async function isUserExists(username) {
  try {
    return await null;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong');
  }
}

async function createUser(username) {
  const isExists = await isUserExists(username)
  if (isExists) {
    throw new Error('username');
  }
  return "Sucessful";
}

createUser("test")
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  })
</script>
```